# JsonServiceClient Posting File with Parameters and Custom Header

Tags: json, client, servicestack, custom-headers

All,

We are trying to post files with data using the latest V3 version of SS, and have finally achieved success with one exception. We are still unable to send a custom header along with the data. Here is what we are trying to post in the header, but it never exists in the header when the request arrives at my SS instance.

```
client.LocalHttpWebRequestFilter = x => { 
    x.Headers.Add("Authorization-KAPI", AuthorizationKAPI); 
};
```

Suggestions please?!?!

Thanks,
B

Comment: Have you tested sending the headers from a local client? Sometimes headers can be removed by proxies or firewalls between you client and the ServiceStack server. Can you provide an example of the `AuthorizationKAPI` string, could there be a character that is prohibited in the header within the string?

Comment: Scott, 

Thanks for your reply. We tested it by stepping it locally between two apps on my dev machine. AuthorizationKAPI is a GUID string.

Thanks,
B

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried dropping the `-KAPI` part to see if the standard `Authorization` header is seen? I suspect it won't make a difference but good to rule it out anyway.

Comment: I am also assuming because you haven't included the other code, that you defining the `JsonServiceClient` then adding the filter, then making the request. And the request is definitely on the now filtered client.

Comment: Scott, we never did get it working using the ServiceStack client. For the file upload, we used RestSharp on the client to our ServiceStack API.

Comment: So is it working with RestSharp? Are you still trying to get it working with the ServiceStack client? Did you try changing the header to just `Authorization`? Have you tried adding the RequestLogger plugin https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger to help diagnose the problem? Add it `Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());` then go `/requestlogs`

Comment: Scott, I'll take a look again at some point. The Authorization-KAPI header is a required custom header which we use to validate our API key within ServiceStack, so I don't think changing to Authorization would help us. Bottom line is we were under a deadline and we got it to work so off we go. At this point any server side processing from the client (read MVC controller in any of the sites) will use RestSharp to communicate with the API.